# Обычный код, для Бота Discord. В чем проблема? Пишет, что нету модуля

Tags: discord, бот, discord.py

[[image: В чем проблема? Код совсем простой, саам код я скопировал, но почему выдаёт ошибку?]**В чем проблема?
Код совсем простой, саам код я скопировал, но почему выдаёт ошибку?**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwfKj.png)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Модуль не установлен
прежде чем запускать необходимо установить [пакет](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)

```
pip install discord.py
```